# exceptions unit testing in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am writing unit tests for this code and I was wondering how would someone test any of the exceptions of the code below. thanks.

```
class ExpiringTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
        """
        Extends token auth with inactivity expiration mechanism.
        """
        model = ExpiringToken

        def authenticate_credentials(self, key):

            try:
                token = self.model.objects.get(key=key)
            except self.model.DoesNotExist:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid token')

            if not token.user.is_active:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid user')

            if token.has_expired():
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Token has expired')

            token.last_activity = timezone.now()
            token.save()
            return token.user, token
```

Comment: At first: which testing framework do you (want to) use?

Comment: I am using Django. (built-in lib TestCase)

Comment: Then you do it like unittest should be done: Create the test givens (User, Tokens), create an instance of your class, run he method check if the exception was raised with `with self.assertRaises(YourError):`.

Comment: that's what i did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664611/attributeerror-bound-method-manager-get-of-django-db-models-manager-manager

Comment: I answered the another question